# C++ new allocates more space than expected

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, new-operator

I am trying to test some c++ app behavior when memory requirements are high, but it seems that I cannot use all of my available ram. I have the following program:

```
class Node {
    public:
        Node *next;
};


int main() {
    int i=0;

    Node *first = new Node();
    Node *last = first;

    //Should be   120000000 * 8 bytes each -> approx 1 GB
    for (i=0; i < 120000000; i++) {
        Node *node = new Node();
        node->next = 0;
        last->next = node;
        last = last->next;
    }


    for (i=0; i < 120000000; i++) {
        Node *oldfirst = first;
        first = first->next;
        delete oldfirst;
    }

    delete first;

    return 0;    
}
```

It is supposed to allocate approx 1 GB of data , simply because Node class occupies 8 bytes. I ve verified this via sizeof, gdb, even valgrind.

This program however allocates about 4 GB of data! If I double this size, ( 120000000 -> 2400000000 ), then there are 2 options (My laptop has 8GB of RAM installed):

- If I have turned off the swap area, the process is killed by the kernel.
- If not, then paging takes place, and OS becomes really slow.

The point is that I cannot test an application that allocates 2 GB of data, because it consumes 8 GB of RAM!

I thought that maybe the bytes allocated when I ask for a new Node are more than 8 (that is the size of the Node object), so I tried the following:

```
class Node {
    public:
        Node *next;
        Node *second_next;
};


int main() {
    int i=0;

    Node *first = new Node();
    Node *last = first;

    //Should be   120000000 * 8 bytes each -> approx 1 GB
    for (i=0; i < 120000000; i++) {
        Node *node = new Node();
        node->next = 0;
        last->next = node;
        last = last->next;
    }


    for (i=0; i < 120000000; i++) {
        Node *oldfirst = first;
        first = first->next;
        delete oldfirst;
    }

    delete first;

    return 0;    
}
```

Now Node object occupies 16 bytes. The memory footprint of the application was exactly the same! 120000000 resulted in 4 GB of RAM used, 240000000 resulted in my app being killed by the Linux kernel.

So I came across [this post](http://prog21.dadgum.com/179.html)

Is it true that every new in C++ allocates at least 32 bytes?

Comment: The exact behavior of the underlying allocator is going to be OS- and system-library-dependent. It's certainly possible that there is some minimum chunk size that it will allocate, but it's impossible to make a general assertion of C++'s behavior, as if you dig down far enough, `operator new` is really just asking for memory from the system, probably via `malloc()`.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a custom allocator or, better yet, use something other than a linked list.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz this is just for demonstration - it's not production code. I wanted to know how dynamically allocated objects are placed in memory, in general.

Comment: Could it be that your OS allocates memory in fixed size chunks? So, if it allocates in chunks of `2^n` it will allocate 128 bytes when you request 120 bytes. If this is correct it would allocate `2^31` bytes (2.15GB) when you request to allocate slightly over 1GB (`2^30` bytes). This is just a guess though. The OS I work with does this, but uses the Fibonacci sequence for chunk sizes.

Comment: Having overhead for memory allocation is totally expected.  I don't know why you are surprised.  You should be aware of that and avoid allocating a lot of small objects.  Instead, use vector.

Comment: @jasonR that must be the case I agree. But I could not imagine that avery new I ve written in C++ allocates 32 bytes (well, at least on Linux). I would expect that the exact amount of memory that was asked would be returned. Anyway, I m going to try this on different C++ implementations.

Comment: malloc/new have an internal overhead storing the  allocated size. In addition the memory management may align the resulting pointer and may round up sizes (to a power of two, or a more sophisticated granulation). Hence, if memory becomes tight, write a custom allocator allocating huge chunks internally.

Comment: What you need is a custom allocator for small objects. There are plenty of them around, e.g boost pool. Or write your own.

Comment: Also, GNU `malloc()` always return 16-byte aligned value on 64 bit x86 systems. If node is 16 bytes long itself, assuming `new` simply calls `malloc`, and `malloc()` stores at least one byte of bookkeeping information, then it cannot be less than 32 bytes for a node.

Comment: Ok you convinced me. Obviously I was missing that memory allocation overhead. Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer - you forgot to factor in the memory allocation overhead. The memory allocator itself needs to keep track of the allocated blocks of memory which in itself consumes memory, and if you're allocating a lot of small blocks the overhead gets unreasonably large compared to the amount of memory you requested. Then there is also the block alignment to think of, a lot of allocators try to be smart and align blocks of memory for optimal CPU access speed, so they'll be aligned to cache lines.

Last but not least, a successful request to give you 8 bytes of memory might well have allocated a much larger chunk behind the scenes. After all, asking malloc/new for a specific amount of memory only guarantees that you'll get a chunk of at least that size, not exactly that size.

For your use case of allocating lots and lots of small chunks, you'd need to look into something like a pool allocator that minimizes the overhead.

Actually, what you should probably consider is a better data structure than a very large linked list with lots of small nodes.

Comment: Smaller objects do not always mean proportionally larger overhead. E.g. an optimized implementation of `malloc` could handle small objects in a different way, by using a pool for them.

Comment: Sure I would never write such production code. I wanted to achieve running out of memory, that's why I wrote this simple implementation. But apparently my perception of memory-management was not correct. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to understand the allocation you are using, it has an 8-byte overhead, 32-byte minimum including overhead and 16-byte alignment.  For example:

1 .. 24 bytes:  takes 32
25 .. 40 bytes: takes 48
41 .. 56 bytes: takes 64
etc.

If you want to use a large number of tiny objects efficiently, you need to allocate them some other way (in bulk and then subdivide the allocation yourself).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the `malloc` implementation.  I tested on my machine (64bit), that if I use `tcmalloc`, it roughly takes 1GB memory.  Internally tcmalloc keep separate pools for different allocation sizes, thus for each pool, there is no need to bookkeeping the object size, which reduces overhead for small objects.  For 8-byte allocation, there is no overhead at all.

```
hidden $ cat c.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node { Node *next; };

int main() {
    Node *first = new Node();
    Node *last = first;
    for (int i=0; i < 120000000; i++) {
        Node *node = new Node();
        node->next = 0;
        last = last->next = node;
    }

    cout << "Press <Enter> to continue...";
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    return 0;
}
hidden $ g++ -std=c++11 -O3 c.cpp /usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4
hidden $ ./a.out & { sleep 5; ps -C a.out -o rss; killall a.out; }
[1] 31500
Press <Enter> to continue...
[1]+  Stopped                 ./a.out
  RSS
947064
```